# Nuxt sweetalet error: [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: this.$swal is not a function"

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, sweetalert2

I just installed [vue-sweetalert2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sweetalert2) in my Nuxt application. After install and adding It to modules, I placed simple swal function into my code:

```
  created() {
    this.$swal("Hello Vue world!!!");
  },
```

Unfortunately I only receive error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: this.$swal is not a function"
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: How have you installed it?

Comment: `npm install -S vue-sweetalert2` like in tutorial

Comment: Ok, with Nuxt there’s a little more to it I’m afraid! You need to create a plug-in. Please read the docs and let me know if you need any further help https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/

Comment: @BobiDaHombre Can you show how you've added it to `modules`? Or link to a reproduction? I cannot reproduce the error.